# implement substring c++

Tags: c++, string

how do you implement substring in C++ that returns pointer to char? (takes pointer to the first letter)

say something like `char* substr(char* c, int pos, int lenght`)

Comment: When you say "implement", do you mean write a substr function that has the signature that you posted above? Or do you mean is there such a function in C++?

Answer (score 4):

I use methods of the [std::string](http://www.google.ca/search?q=std%3A%3Astring) class.

---

Edit:

> say something like char* substr(char* c, int pos, int lenght)

This isn't a function that it's possible to implemement well. To create a substring, you need memory:

- Same memory as original string: did you mean to overwrite the original string? Is the original string writeable?
- New memory: is the caller going to invoke the delete[] operator on the pointer which it receives from your `substr` function (if it doesn't, there would be a memory leak)?
- Global memory: you could reserve a fixed-length buffer in global memory, but that's all sorts of problems (may not be long enough, will be overwritten when someone else calls your `substr`).

The right way to do it is to return a `std::string` instance, which is what the `string::substr` method does, as shown in [Graphics Noob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469151/implement-substring-c/1469212#1469212), because the `std::string` instance (unlike a `char*` instance) will manage the lifetime of its own memory; and if you then want a `char*` instance from the `std::string` instance, you can get that using the `c_str()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the functionality you are trying to replicate?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/

Comment: Link is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
str.substr(int,int).c_str()
```

Will return the substring as a `const char*` but be careful using it, the memory containing the string will be invalid at the end of the statement, so you may need to surround it with a `strcpy()` if you want to store the result. Or better yet just break it up into two lines:

```
std::string str2 = str.substr(int,int);
const char* cstr = str2.c_str();
```

You'll need to do a strcpy() to safely get rid of the `const`.

The `int`s refer to the parameters for the substring you're trying to get.